# «Уже» может быть зависимым словом?

Tags: раздельно, слитно

Фраза:«Уже не существующий отдел». Писать слитно или раздельно? «Уже» здесь зависимое слово или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отдел **уже не существует**. Уже **не существующий отдел**.

Уже ― **временное наречие**, поэтому оно придает причастию значение действия и,  соответственно,  в первую очередь **относится к зависимым словам.**

**Пример:**

«Вам передадут письмо, если я буду убит, ― писал мой, **уже не существующий**, товарищ. [Владимир Дудинцев. Новогодняя сказка (1965)]

**УЖЕ**. I. нареч. Случилось наступило, совершилось (какое-л. действие, состояние). У. наступила ночь. У. кто-л. приехал. У. поправился. У. начался урок. У. было поздно.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (почему зависимые слова влияют на написание НЕ с причастиями)

**Причастие** — это особая  форма глагола, которая обозначает **действие** как отнесенный ко времени **признак** предмета. В форме причастия совмещаются грамматические признаки глагола и прилагательного.

(1) Мы считаем, что **одиночное** причастие начинает в большей степени проявлять признаки прилагательного, но при этом **не исключаем** его из класса причастий.  Как же это сказывается на правилах?

В одиночных формах (без зависимых слов) мы по-прежнему пишем НН (как в причастиях), но частица НЕ пишется слитно (как и для прилагательных), например: *окрашенная скамейка, законченный роман, неокрашенная скамейка, незаконченный роман.*

(2) Но при наличии ЗАВИСИМЫХ слов, перешедших в причастный оборот **из глагольного словосочетания**, действие приобретает **реальные черты** и становится **более значимым** – теперь частица НЕ пишется раздельно (отрицание действия).

Признаки действия (**проявление во времени**) особенно заметны при наличии **временных наречий**: **еще** не законченный роман, **до сих пор** не покрашенная скамейка.